# How can i check through an if-statement if a TextField is an integer or not?

Tags: swift, if-statement

How can i check through an if-statement if a TextField is an integer or not ?

```
@IBAction func Clickme2(sender: AnyObject) {
if TextField2.text == Int()  {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( Int(textField2.text) == nil) {
    //In this case, your text is not an integer
}
```

This works perfectly fine since Swift has those fancy failable Initializers which prevent your app from crashing when you pass invalid parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can check it the textField text property is not nil and if it can be converted to Int:

```
guard let text = textField2.text, integer = Int(text) else { return }
print(integer)
```

If you just need to know if it text property has an Integer you can create a computed property to return true or false as follow:

```
extension UITextField {
    var isInteger: Bool {
        guard let text = text else { return false }
        return Int(text) != nil
    }
}
```

usage:

```
if textField2.isInteger  {
      // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check " 1 2 3  " as int,you can do like this:

```
@IBAction func Clickme2(sender: AnyObject) {
    var text = TextField2.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    if let integer = Int(text) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

If you only want to check "  123   " as int,you can do like this:

```
@IBAction func Clickme2(sender: AnyObject) {
    var text = TextField2.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet())
    if let integer = Int(text) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```